# Ubuntu on Intel z8350 (chuwi hi10 pro)?

Tags: 18.04, crash

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my chuwi hi10 pro that has a 1920*1200 display and touch and has a intel z8350(cherry trial) cpu.

When booting Ubuntu from the install USB without installing to try out, it works bad. I mean, it works, but Firefox crashes after 15 minutes, and after 25 minutes apps won't start anymore or whole Ubuntu crashes. Also, brightness controller and touch doesn't work. Now is touch not mandatory, but brightness and stability is.
Desktop is also a bit slow, probably because missing gpu drivers?

So what can I do to solve my problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently switched from Manjaro to Ubuntu 18.10

A few things:

a) for touchscreen:

You must follow these steps:
 
1.  Install the driver: 
     
Clone the repository from https://github.com/onitake/gslx680-acpi
     
make 
     
insmod ./gslx680_ts_acpi.ko
     
Then you need the correct firmware (you must select the correct Chuwi Hi 10 Pro model (based on the beginning of the serial number), rename silead_ts.fw to mssl1680.fw:
     
https://github.com/onitake/gsl-firmware/tree/master/firmware/chuwi
     
Then you must calibrate the screen. A script, which you can run with startup applications is at https://github.com/danielotero/linux-on-hi10/blob/master/touchscreen/rotation
    
You may need to change "DSI1" to "DSI-1" 

 2. Audio: Ubuntu 18.10 already has it setup mostly so all you need to do is:
    
 copy the code from: https://gist.github.com/Orochimarufan/d8e42cfaa32c2cdd13640dad6a10b847 and save it as speakerEnable.c
    
 Then: make
    
 This program must run as root when you login therefore, you must turn it into a service to run on startup (unless you manually want to do ./speakerEnable every time you want the speakers) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202698/how-can-i-run-a-program-as-a-root-user-when-my-ubuntu-15-04-machine-starts-up

 I hope the instructions are clear. If you need clarification on how to make (compile a c program) or anything else, please ask. It took a while to get the tablet configured nicely.

Comment: Only component not working correctly is Bluetooth (the people who made the driver are working on making a proper driver for newer Linux OS') and some scaling issues (high resolution on a small screen).

Answer (score 0):

I recently switched from Manjaro to Ubuntu 18.10
A few things:
a) for touchscreen:
You must follow these steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/onitake/gslx680-acpi
cd gslx680-acpi
make
```

and then load module

```
insmod ./gslx680_ts_acpi.ko
```

Running dmesg should produce some output if the device was matched by the driver. You should also see a message from the input subsystem that a new input device was added.

More info on https://github.com/onitake/gslx680-acpi.

Answer (score 0):

I did what sheldonm301  suggested and I can get my touchscreen working, but I find when I restart the tablet the mod seems to be removed from the lsmod command and touchscreen is no longer working. So I created a .sh file to run when I start the tablet and want the touchscreen to work. The code looks like this

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/onitake/gslx680-acpi
git clone https://github.com/onitake/gsl-firmware
cd gslx680-acpi
make
sudo insmod ./gslx680_ts_acpi.ko
cd
sudo cp gsl-firmware/firmware/chuwi/hi10_pro/silead_ts.fw /lib/firmware/
sudo mv /lib/firmware/silead_ts.fw /lib/firmware/mssl1680.fw
rm -r gslx680-acpi
rm -r gsl-firmware
```

You can also copy this into a .sh file and run it to perform the fixing method suggested by sheldonm301 
Another resource with same solution [here](https://jonathansblog.co.uk/ubuntu-on-the-chuwi-hi10-pro)