# Touchscreen in Ubuntu 22.04 MATE on Chuwi Hi10 Plus

Tags: drivers, touchscreen, ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

I'm using a Ubuntu 22.04 MATE on a **Chuwi Hi10 plus**, all works fine; the sound, the wi-fi, the battery... etc

But the touchscreen isn't works, I tried to install a driver but nothing has been changed.
Do you know a solution?? A driver to install or something like that?

Thanks!!

Comment: "I tried to install a driver": which driver? how did you install it?

Comment: @Esther I followed this post, it's the most recent I found:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047180/ubuntu-on-intel-z8350-chuwi-hi10-pro#1219044

Comment: you need to substitute `hi10_plus` for `hi10_pro` in the commands there, because you have a different model so you need different firmware. Other thing is that driver is very old, so might not work with newer kernels

Comment: I just do it and isn't works, should be a old driver...

Comment: Can I ask how you boot your Hi10+? I installed Ubuntu22.04 on mine, deleted all old partitions and still I have the Android Bootloader in the beginning (with only the Android Icon, Windows vanished after clean). I can only boot with F7 from the boot menu (which I cannot change in BIOS, save wont save). Thanks